# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I was reading this [Is it normal for a junior programmer to be alone in a project?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/194488/is-it-normal-for-a-junior-programmer-to-be-alone-in-a-project), and the last answer https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/194532/271 was deleted by a moderator.  There’s no comment, and the answer doesn’t seem inappropriate.

Do such deletions normally include a comment saying why?

Comment: Often mods don't include a reason (that you can see), but we never delete without a good reason and it is sometimes communicated direct to the OP

Comment: Just after a 3 second look, it smells like AI generated. It is bland generic advice, with no reference or acknowledgement of the actual question asked. I did not put the work in to rigorously test it, as the mod deleting it did, but I would not doubt it for a second that this was just generator output, not a human writing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was me that deleted it, and as nvoigt suspected in their comment it was for being AI generated

Comment: Thanks, that also explains the odd slant to the answer.